# iOS Build Resubmission in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submit one build in  App Store. They rejected the build due to some network issues. I checked again and again to reproduce the issue , but I could not.  So I submitted the same binary again. They rejected again.

My question is :- 
Should I take new binary if one is rejected (even if no change in binary) ??

Thank You

Comment: no need to take any new binary if there is no change in your code.

Answer (score 1):

> No

You don't have to reupload new binary if there is no change in code. 
Contact Apple resolution center and submit an appeal.
You can find link to submit an appeal from [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/)

Answer (score 0):

If your submission was "binary rejected" you can re-submit the same binary but is usefull. If you build was rejected for any reason and you don't change anything there's no reason because your binary the second time may be acepted. This is the theory.

So first of all try to investigate on the reason by contacting apple support as suggested by @Muhammad Adnan.

In my esperience my app was rejected because reviewer said that crashed two times. I've try to reproduce the issues with no luck. Finally I re-submit the binary increasing the built number  and  some minor change in the code:

**The app was approved.**